# Replacing strings using sed and a file as input

Tags: for-loop, sed

I have a bunch of files, in a lot of different folders that I need to edit. 
Each folder has a subfolder that has another subfolder nested in it. 
I have the folder names (genome_list.txt) and each the files that need to be edited have the same name in all the folders. 
I want to use a list of strings from one file, to delete such strings from another file. 
Here is what my failed attempt to do so looks like

```
for dir in $(cat genome_list.txt)
do 
cd ${dir}/ref_map_${dir}
for samplename in $(cat remove_from_samples.txt )
do 
sed -i 's/${samplename}//g' ../samples.txt
done
cd ../..
done
```

Files look like this:

```
 cat remove_from_samples.txt
 -s CHJ111.fq
 -s CHJ727.fq

 cat samples.txt
 -s CHJ062.fq -s CHJ111.fq -s CHJ522.fq -s CHJ_528.fq -s CHJ727.fq

 #Desired output:
 -s CHJ062.fq -s CHJ522.fq -s CHJ_528.fq
```

Comment: What is failing? Are you cd'ing into the expected directories and just having a problem with the `sed` part? If so, can you show some part of the `remove_from_samples.txt` and `samples.txt` files along with what you expect that version of `samples.txt` to look like after running sed?

Comment: yes. I believe the sed part is the one doing me wrong. I will edit the question to include examples.

Comment: Use `read` instead of `for` to read a line at a time, instead of space-delimited tokens:  `while read s; do sed -i "s/${s}//g" samples.txt; done < remove_from_samples.txt`

Comment: Not an answer but mebbe use 'pushd/popd' instead of 'cd foo/bar; ...; cd ../..' - or do the work in a subshell. In fact, it would be better to avoid the 'cd' altogether IMO. Just a matter of clarity and maintainability.

Comment: I think @jas has a good approach - have you tried it?

Comment: yes! it worked perfectly!

Comment: in the question the sed command is single-quoted so the shell variable won't be expanded